# Why is confidence in U.S. banking at 27%?

Tags: united-states, public-opinion, currency, federal-reserve, banking

> "Gallup first measured confidence in institutions in 1973 and has done so annually since 1993. This year's survey was conducted June 1-20.": "Now I am going to read you a list of institutions in American society. Please tell me how much confidence you, yourself, have in each one -- a great deal, quite a lot, some or very little." [73% said, "'some', or 'very little.'"](https://news.gallup.com/poll/394283/confidence-institutions-down-average-new-low.aspx)

[image: gallup confidence]

Comment: It's really difficult to answer. The direct answer is because 27% of responders said so. But why did they say so? Only they know for sure. Maybe they simply don't like banks as much. And look there is stuff in which confidence is even lower. Whatever that means.

Comment: @JamesK I personally think confidence in a business comes from being honest and offering a la carte consent (Condorcet). *Why should **anyone** have **just some confidence or none** in the party they are dealing with if the commerce and justice department are working?* Are people exchanging hours and goods at these institutions based on *little* threats and/or *multipartite, unreasonably-intractable* duress?

Comment: @JamesK Why are you trying to make *confidence* a subjective question?

Comment: @NickCarducci Because the poll treats it as such. It is not objectively measuring confidence (however that would look like). The question even specifies " you, yourself" which is a clear indicator of subjectivity.

Comment: Based on coincidence maybe the change in Federal Funds Rate? Like it massively increased over the last year, making saving money more attractive but also making loans without fixed rates more expensive?

Comment: @haxor789 Interest rates on bank savings accounts remain negligible despite increases in the fed fund rates. They are markedly less than the currently high inflation rate. I am not at all confident they will increase. OTOH, I am quite confident that banks will charge higher interest rates on a loan. I would not conflate that confidence in higher rates with confidence in the banking institutions.

Comment: Polls have a basic problem: They are no longer polling a cross section of the country, and they are finding it harder and harder correct the mismatch. I'm an old fart and even I hardly ever answer a call from an unknown number. Text me first if I don't know who you are, and that way I might answer. There's a problem here: you can't text my landline. Polls still rely largely on landlines. If a pollster did text me beforehand and I said "sure" (ain't gonna happen) and they asked me about confidence in polls I would answer that negatively. Another problem is that the question is very subjective.

Comment: Any time the phrase **Too big to fail** is in play, it implies a complete lack of confidence.  The mere fact that you're discussing how to prop them up presupposes that the institution(s) in question are unable to survive on their own merits.

Comment: @DavidHammen On-site polling? By Email or even by mail? Like you could easily use information about a persons political and economical views to asses their income, education, their working hours and how protected their house is, without raising much suspicion. So unsolicited phone calls asking you a catalogue of questions is quite odd to have remained.

Comment: I know we are not supposed to use comments to make comments but...organized labor is trusted more than the Supreme Court?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the [historical data](https://news.gallup.com/poll/1597/confidence-institutions.aspx) for that poll might offer some insight.

Until 2006, of those asked, around 50% had a "great deal / quite a lot" of confidence in banks (comparable to confidence in churches in that year, and better than confidence in the supreme court, public schools, newspapers, or the criminal justice system).

With the [financial crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2007%E2%80%932008_financial_crisis) 07/08, those numbers took a nosedive, bottoming out at 21% in 2012. They recovered a bit, but never really reached those previous heights.

We can see another small height of 38% in 2020, which declined again in 21/22 to 33/27%, coinciding with the [covid-19 recession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_recession) and [2021-2022 inflation surge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2021%E2%80%932022_inflation_surge). While banks may or may not have a direct impact on those crisis, in a time of financial hardship people will have more negative interactions with institutions that offer them credit, mortgages, etc, which may erode their trust.

Answer (score 3):

Banks and bankers are not "popular".  They seem to be making money (lots of money) without actually making anything.

And that's when things are going well, when things go badly people can loose their life savings.

These polls tend to turn into a measure of popularity.

So it is not surprising that people rank banks lowly on any particular scale.  It matters little if you ask if they are "trustworthy", "socially useful" or "environmentally friendly" (!) If you ask people to say good or bad things about bankers, they will say bad things, because they don't like them.

Comment: I think this is part of it, but "seem to" carries a lot of weight here. In a capitalist society, banks may not produce physical goods, but they do offer services that can be (perceived as) useful (they give people a mortgage which allows them to own homes, they offer loans so people can buy cars and other big purchases, they provide a secure place to store their money, and may help to invest it). I think how people weight these benefits against (perceived or actual) misdeeds by banks is an important part in how confident people are in these institutions.

Comment: @tim As more and more people understand the scam of fiat money and malinvestment, people will understand that banks, central banks, and financiers are just parasites.

Comment: @paulj I'm very uncomfortable with that idea & terminology. It's rooted in antisemitic imagery and centuries old tropes about productive vs non-productive capital. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_parasite